# What is the easiest way to add <a> tag to a <h1> tag in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for the easiest way to add a `<a>` tag to an `<h1>` in a react Navbar.  The links for all of the other pages work just fine through a different method, but I would like to link the Heading back to my Homepage.

Here is the Navabr.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItems } from "./MenuItems";
import './Stylesheets/Navbar.css'

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    state = { clicked: false }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <nav className="NavbarItems">
                ***<h1 className="Navbar-logo">Tickets<i className="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i></h1>***
                <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
        
                    
                </div>
                <ul className={ this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                                {item.title}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}     
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

I am tring to link eveerything in the `<h1>` back to the homepage.

Comment: are you using react router? If yes, take a look at [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) component

Comment: Why not just add the tag?

Comment: @Alejandro If the above example is CRA and React Router is used then using Link component will preserve state and avoid refresh - which can be useful in some cases.

Comment: @PunitMakwana I understand that, but I am pretty new to react and I am not sure how to structure it within the <h1>

Comment: @rskybsn you initiated project with create-react-app?

Comment: @PunitMakwana yes, and I am utilizing the React-Router-Dom

Answer (score 0):

Try React-router-dom.
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Here is some quick introduction, but all of it you can read in official documentation.

After installing you can import it

```
Import {ReactRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from ‘react-router-dom’
```

Then you can simply specify to which page user will be redirected after click on Link

In return :

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path=‘/’>
        //home page content
    </Route>

    <Route path=‘/about’>
        //About us page content
    </Route>

   <Route path=‘/contact’>
        //contact page content
    </Route>

  </Switch>
</Router>
```

And then instead of a elements use Link element which you’ve imported

```
<nav>
  <Link to=‘/’>Home</Link>
  <Link to=‘/about’>About us</Link>
  <Link to=‘/contact’>Contact</Link>
</nav>
```

Comment: @PunitMakwana I have done all of that.  My routing is working.  I am just trying to link this one element back to the homepage.

```<h1 className="Navbar-logo">Tickets<i className="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i></h1>```

Comment: @rskybsn host an reproducible example on codesandbox